# Symfony3: Контроллер не видит пользователя, авторизация которого произведена из PHPUnit

Tags: symfony2, symfony, phpunit, symfony3

У меня есть функция для авторизации тестового пользователя

```
/**
 * Login function for user.
 *
 * @param Client $client
 */
private function logIn(Client $client)
{
    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('DWDAdminBundle:User')->find(1);

    $firewall = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, ['ROLE_ADMIN']);
    $client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

В тестируемом экшене есть кусок кода, которому нужен текущий пользователь
$this->getUser()

```
$checkResult = $this->get('dwd.service.coupon')->checkCoupon(
            $coupon,
            $request->query->all(),
            $this->getUser()->getPortalId()
        );
```

И почему-то в этом месть метод getUser() возвращает Null, хотя я провел авторизацию в setUp() в тесте

```
/**
 * Sets up some stuff before test running
 */
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->logIn($this->client);

}
```

Comment: Вам помогло это? у меня ровно точно такая-же ситуация и мне это не помогает всё равно возвращает null? не надо ли создать мок юзера и токена и добавить как-то это в контейнер?

Answer (score 0):

Более предпочтительный вид тестирования аутентификации - авторизация через HTTP.
Она описана здесь более подробно: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html

Вам следует включить авторизацию по HTTP в тестовом окружении, примерно так:

`config_test.yml:`

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            http_basic: ~
```

в файле теста:

```
$credentials = [
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'testuser',
    'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => '111',
];
$client = static::createClient([], $credentials);
```